# How to use JLayered Pane to display an image on top of another image?

Tags: image, swing, graphics, jlayeredpane, pacman

We are working on a pacman game and we want to add a picture of pacman on top of the background.
If someone could provide some example code of implementing the Jlayered Pane that would be great.

Here is some of the code we attempted to write. When we try to run it, nothing displays:

```
  JLayeredPane pacman = new JLayeredPane();  

  pacman.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(576, 655));





  ImageIcon sprite = new ImageIcon("C:\\\\Users\\\\16ayoubc\\\\Desktop\\\\Pacman-moving.gif");  
  ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("C:\\\\Users\\\\16ayoubc\\\\Desktop\\\\background.png");  

  JLabel pacmansprite = new JLabel(sprite);
  JLabel background1 = new JLabel(background);

  background1.setVisible(true);
  pacman.setLocation(255, 255);
  pacman.setVisible(true);
  pacman.setOpaque(true);

  pacman.add(background1, new Integer(0));
```

Comment: For a situation like this you might be better off just [painting things yourself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) in a single component. The Swing component hierarchy is really meant for constructing UIs with buttons, text fields, and stuff like that.

Comment: You didn't accept any of the answer from your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/23061863/131872), so I think I'll skip this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should just add a canvas to the `JLayeredPane`, and than paint the image using `java2D` (found in `java.awt.Graphics`, and `java.awt.Graphics2D`. More info on this is available.). than, try using the `Graphics2D` method `drawImage(BufferedImage img, int x, int y, int width, int hight);`.  This may be complicated, but it might work better.

I hope this works!